# scala replace function with camma as ","

Tags: scala

The below Input i have to replace last comma (,) with "," between two colons(:)

```
println(input)
//[level:1,File:one,three,Flag:NA][level:1,File:two,Flag:NA]
println(input.replace(",", "\",\""))
```

getting result as:

```
//[level:1","File:one","three","Flag:NA][level:1","File:two","Flag:NA]
```

expected result should be

```
[level:1","File:one,three","Flag:NA][level:1","File:two","Flag:NA]
```

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val str1 = "[level:1,File:one,three,Flag:NA][level:1,File:two,Flag:NA]"

val regex1 = raw"(,)(\w+:)".r

val matches = regex1.findAllMatchIn(str1)

val str2 = matches.foldLeft(str1)({ case (str, m) =>
  str.replaceFirst(m.group(0), "\",\"" + m.group(2))
})
// str2: String = [level:1","File:one,three","Flag:NA][level:1","File:two","Flag:NA]
```